# Random Forest: R code to identify the specific correctly-predicted records

Tags: r, machine-learning, rstudio, random-forest, prediction

Using the simple example dataset "iris", with "trainData" to train a Random Forest model and "testData"  to predict/classify Species.

```
# 1 - Create a Random Forest Model. 
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=trainData)  
# 2 - Predict using Model and Test data set 
iris.pred <- predict(iris.rf, testData)  
# 3 - Show Crosstab results:
table(observed = testData$Species, predicted = iris.pred)
```

***Question:***
Step #3 above,
gives you a table with the total number
of test records classified correctly and incorrectly.

What is the R code to get a list of the *specific records* in "testData",
which have been:
  **(a)** predicted correctly -or-
  **(b)** *NOT* predicted correctly,
        (ie: the predicted $Species is wrong).

***Reason for my Question:***
I'm trying to find out
if there is some valuable insight
by looking at *specific*, individual records
which have been misclassified in a Random Forest session.

Maybe this is an additional (possible) way
of improving the accuracy
of the Random Forest prediction...

Comment: Maybe I'm being stupid here but can you have a "true positive" with a classification problem that isn't binary?

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, I think you need a binary outcome variable to look into specificity and sensitivity, but here's a start at your answer:

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)
set.seed(44)
indexes = sample(2, length(iris), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3,0.7))
trainData<-iris[indexes==2,]
testData<-iris[indexes==1,]
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=trainData)
iris.pred <- predict(iris.rf, testData)

truePositives<-which(iris.pred==testData$Species)
falsePositives<-which(iris.pred!=testData$Species)
truePositives
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
[24] 25 26 27 28 29 30
falsePositives
[1] 15

head(testData[truePositives,])
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
21          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2  setosa
26          5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: Thank you, Jason.  Maybe I used the wrong terminology.           I was referring to identifying the specific test records shown in:     table(observed = testData$Species, predicted = iris.pred)  
##             predicted
## observed     setosa versicolor virginica
##   setosa          8          0         0
##   versicolor      0          6         1
##   virginica       0          1        10

Comment: For my example you could run `table(testData$Species,iris.pred)`